# Is the function increasing?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $S,T$ be two well ordered sets of rational numbers with the ordering of the rationals.

Let $f:S\mapsto T$ be an injective function.

I want to check if there is an injective Function from S to T that is increasing.

Could you give me a hit for that? Do we use the ordering?

Comment: All injective functions are increasing?  What about $x\mapsto -x$?

Comment: I edited the question.. I want to check if there exist such a function that is increasing @lulu

Comment: The edit does not help.  What has $f$ got to do with anything in the new version? 
 More to the point:  Obviously the existence of an injective function between two sets depends on the two sets.

Comment: So can we not check that with the given data? @lulu

Comment: If you mean that existence of injective function guarantees the existance of strictly increasing function, then the answer is no. Just let $S$ be of order type $\omega + 1$ and let $T$ be of order type $\omega$. There is an injection since both are countable. But there is no order-preserving injection from $S$ into $T$.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri  Though here we know that $S,T$ are either finite or countable (as they are subsets of $\mathbb Q$).

Comment: @DuncanRamage, As I stated, there is none from $S$ into $T$. Of course there is going to be one from the other direction.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Already realized my mistake and deleted it :)

Comment: @lulu, I don't understand your concern.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri  I think I misread your point..disregard my earlier comment.  Your counterexample is correct.

Answer (score 4):

No, there may not exist an order preserving injection. Let $T = \{1 - \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N^+}\}$ and let $S = T \cup \{1\}$. Both of these sets are well ordered, and both of them are countable so there exists a bijection between them, but $T$ has the order type of $\omega$ and $S$ has the order type of $\omega + 1$, so there can't be an order preserving injection from $S$ to $T$, as it would imply an order preserving injection from $\omega + 1$ to $\omega$.

Comment: I don't think you need AC here. Atleast I don't see any clear use.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Covering my bases. I'm not familiar with the ordinals without AC so I didn't want to risk saying anything foolish. I'll remove that note.

Comment: Yeah dealing with choice gets tricky at times. I'm always on the watch for those constructivists too. :P